# Does Light (EM Signal) undergo accelration during reflection?

Tags: speed-of-light, acceleration

Since Average acceleration is defined as,
Average acceleration over a period of time is the change in Velocity divided by the Duration of the Period.

Does Light (EM Wave) undergo acceleration during reflection from mirror or any other surface?

Comment: Duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52008/

Comment: A good question is: Do the photons "bounce" off the mirror, or are they absorbed and new ones emitted?

Answer (score 0):

There is always a change of velocity after reflection. So in a sense 'yes'.