# Does light accelerate when it meets a surface?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, speed-of-light, reflection

Does light accelerate when it meets a surface like mirror, we know that light changes path when it meets a surface like mirror.If light changes path,even if travelling at c,this means light has accelerated.Does this happen? Because according to the theory of special relativity,light does not accelerate!

Or is it like this,light meets a surface like mirror(no reflection of light happens),and mirror absorbs light and re-emits the light again,equal to the angle of incidence, that reaches my eye.

What actually happens? Does light get absorbed and re-emitted by the surface(no reflection of light takes place), or it does get accelerated,i.e. light changes its direction when it meets a surface?

I have already seen that question but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does light accelerate or slow down during reflection?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52008/)

Comment: Acceleration is a vector quantity that is defined as the rate at which velocity (a vector with speed and direction)  changes. It's direction, not "speed" that changes here.  Otherwise, could you not set up a system of mirrors and really get light moving as fast as you like?