# Photon behaviour

Tags: photons

What happens when a photon hits a mirror?
Does the photon decelerate instantaneously to zero and then accelerates instantaneously to the velocity of light when it is reflected from the mirror? 
How do we identify individual photons? How do we know it is the same photon that hit the mirror which is reflected back?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35177/50583