# Speed of light when it reflects from a surface

Tags: speed-of-light, reflection

I have studied in school that the speed of light is always a constant, my question is what is happening when it reflect from a surface? when it hit a surface weather the velocity reached to zero and again increase to speed of light?

I only have high school knowledge of Physics. Please explain me in layman's terms.

Comment: Related: [What is happening at a atomic level when light hits an object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325346/what-is-happening-at-a-atomic-level-when-light-hits-an-object) [What happens when a photon hits a mirror?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/what-happens-when-a-photon-hits-a-mirror), [How do mirrors work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/how-do-mirrors-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of light isn't always constant! light moves at different speeds in different mediums. For example, a prism, where the different wavelengths move at different speeds causing it to split.

With regards to a mirror, it stays constant. Imagine a string attached to a wall. If you send a wave down it, the wave does not stop at the wall, but reflects in the opposite direction, and the same happens with light (which acts as both a wave and a particle)

Comment: Typically the statement 'speed of light is constant' implies *in vacuum*.

Comment: Yep, so not ALWAYS constant =)

Comment: The intention of my statement was to alert you that it's not really relevant for you to correct that point when the implication of OP's statement is correct.

Comment: Forgive me, I was only trying to help further their understanding. I did not think that was a bad thing.