# How to calculate plasma frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, plasma-physics, plasmon

i am wondering about Plasma frequency magnitude. According to the image i want to plot that graph.[image]

Comment: Suspected source of the plot: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366916

Answer (score 1):

Everything shown in the plot is in normalized units.  That is, the frequency, $\omega$, is normalized to the plasma frequency, $\omega_{p}$, and the wave number, $k$, is normalized to the *inertial length* or *skin depth*, $c/\omega_{p}$.

So you need only redefine the dispersion relation to:
$$
\frac{ \omega }{ \omega_{p} } = \sqrt{ 1 + \left( \frac{ k \ c }{ \omega_{p} } \right)^{2} } \tag{0}
$$
then basically plot this like you were plotting:
$$
Y = \sqrt{ 1 + X^{2} } \tag{1}
$$

The dashed line just goes to:
$$
\frac{ \omega }{ \omega_{p} } = \frac{ k \ c }{ \omega_{p} } \tag{2}
$$

Comment: This is correct. The equation in the legend may have been confusing, $\omega=\sqrt{\omega_p^2 + c^2 k^2}$. When you write this in code, it's best to work in dimensionless variables, so what was plotted was indeed $Y(X)$ above

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really sure what you are trying to ask but if you look at where k=0, your frequency becomes the plasma frequency I.e. the y-intercept of your graph.

Comment: i want to plot the dispersion law, but i do not know what should i replace for ''n'' and ''k''?!
''n'' is parameter in the omega p.

Comment: Can you please put all this in the original question clearly?

Comment: according to that image, i want to convert the dispersion law (w=sqrt(c^2*k^2)+wp^2) into matlab and get the same graph, but after plotting the figure is not similar to the attached image! Also wp^2=n*e^2/m*ebsilon zero.

can you give me guideline for plotting?