# Non-reflective material becomes reflective why?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

Why an object (which is opaque) and non reflective becomes reflective if seen from a certain angle . Like I was seeing
grey plastic it became reflective when I saw it at a near parallel angle to surface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does light reflect more intensely when it hits a surface at a large angle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12035/)