# What quantum mechanical property allows for reflection?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection

What are the quantum circumstances that manifest reflection?

Also, to what precision does the wave reflect and is that verified or only speculated by model?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10301/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/ , and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34911/ for starters

Comment: Reflection begins with photons being absorbed and then re-emitted in random directions. It takes billions and billions of photons doing this on a surface to reflect an image.

Comment: I did search before I posted the question Dwagg. Perhaps this Q should be deleted.

Comment: @RandyZeitman there’s nothing wrong with your question. Partial reflection is even more interesting.

Comment: Yes, it's a good question ... but it's also a repeat is what I mean.
"This question already has an answer..."