# Quantization of energy

Tags: atomic-physics, reflection

A mirror reflects all electromagnetic waves that fall on it in the visible spectrum. How does the mechanism of reflection work? Is it because when a photon hits an electron, the electron jumps to a higher energy level and then to come back to its initial energy level, it emits a photon.

If the energy levels of an atom are quantized, how can a mirror absorb all e.m waves in the visible spectrum? Shouldn`t it absorb only specific wavelengths?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32483/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Here's another: physics.stackexchange.com/q/446093. Please take a look at my, the second, answer. Light is elastically scattering off collective electronic degrees of freedom in the mirror.