# Explanation of photon reflection

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection

What occurs in atomic scale that cause the photon to be reflected?
In other words, what is the reason for photons to change its direction and why material can reflect certain wavelengths and absorb the rest? What are the atomic properties that causes that behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does reflection work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10301/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain reflection laws at the atomic level](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/2451

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading about [Compton Scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).