# Wave direction and refraction

Tags: waves, refraction

Why does the direction of a mechanical wave change in refraction?

[image]

Comment: Similar question answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/why-does-light-change-direction-when-it-travels-through-glass).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does light change direction when it travels through glass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/why-does-light-change-direction-when-it-travels-through-glass)

Comment: Are you asking about a mechanical wave or a light wave (ray)?