# How physicists explained straight line propagation of Light thinking of light as wave?

Tags: visible-light, waves

To explain the fact that light travels in a straight line assuming light as a wave physicist said that it has small wavelength. So how does the small wavelength explains the property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If light rays obey to the wave equation, why can they be thought as straight lines?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65237/). If the answers there don't address your question, or you don't understand them, please edit your post to explain why so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

**It does not.**

Neglecting huge gravitational fields (e.g. black holes), which distort even the traveling path of light, **a light wave propagates in a straight line**.

The "wave" part is expressed in the electric and magnetic field of the light beam/pulse, but these two fields oscillate in the plane transverse to the propagation direction.

Lastly, the wavelength only describes how fast these fields oscillate or - using another terminology - how big the period of the field wave is or - using yet another terminology - how far the light has traveled until the field waves begin to repeat themselves.