# Does gravitational lensing violate Fermat's Principle that light must travel in straight lines?

Tags: general-relativity, optics, visible-light, reference-frames, variational-principle

Does bending of light due to warping of space violate Fermat's Principle or is it that in the principle light goes in a straight line with respect to space (taking space as the reference) and in Relativity that reference itself is bending and so does the light?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fermat's principle is a bit more complicated than what you state: it says that in travelling from $A$ to $B$, light will go along the paths that will minimize the time taken to get there - and these may or may not be straight lines. (See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle).)

That said, the gravitational lensing of light does not operate quite like that. Since it is in vacuum, Fermat's principle demands that light travel *locally* in straight lines, which indeed it does: it travels in a [null geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity). However, since spacetime itself is curved, the path *appears* to bend with respect to the flat-space metric you'd have without the Sun's presence.

Answer (score 1):

Well, needless to say that in *curved* space, one should use [Fermat's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_principle) for a *curved* space, which for instance is worked out in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/461402/2451). The solutions are geodesics wrt. the [optical path length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length). They satisfy a [ray equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43711/2451). It was shown in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/461407/2451) that this ray equation correctly accounts for the [bending/deflection of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens).