# In what cases do we use the Routh Function?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

As many of you, I studied Lagrangian Mechanics and Hamiltonian Mechanics, with the so famous functions called Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ and Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ related by:

$$\mathcal{H}(q_i, p_i, t) = \sum_i p_i\ \dot{q}_i - \mathcal{L}(q, \dot{q}, t)$$

Recently I found also another strange function, called the Routh function, or Routhian $\mathcal{R}$ which I didn't get at all. It's considered to be a sort of hybrid formulation between Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, and I also have read the Wikipedia page about it (cfr. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics) but I didn't really get its whole meaning.

May anyone explain its use and meaning with a small example? Also I was wondering why it's not that used. For example in Quantum Field Theory we are always almost satisfied with Lagrangians and rarely with Hamiltonians, for what I studied until now. What about a Routhian formulation of field theory? Would it be a redundant useless question?

Thank you for every hint and your time.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79549/50583) consists of a short review of the Routhian and its application to an example.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I tried to search before to ask but I didn't find it.. thank you so much! Since I guess that answer answers perfectly to my question, should I close/delete  it?

Comment: If you think that a good answer to your question, I'd say flag your own question as duplicate of it.