# How does one derive Fermat's principle of Least Time?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, variational-principle

> Fermat's principle states that the path taken by a ray between two given points is the path that can be traveled in the least time.

I understand that Fermat's principle of Least time is crucial in the derivation of Snell's Law. However, I have yet to come across a satisfying and intuitive answer of why Fermat's principle is true. A lot of derivations don't explain *why* you do said steps.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82737/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic oh I didn't notice that