# Photon momentum in Snell's law of refraction

Tags: optics, photons, momentum, conservation-laws, refraction

In the drivation of Snell's law for light as EM waves, we have the wave vector components parallel to the interface $k1\parallel$ = $k2\parallel$ as shown in the picture.

[image]

From $k_{1x} = k_{2x}$, we have $k_1sin\theta_1 = k_2sin\theta_2$. From the well known equations below,
$$ 
\frac{k_2}{k_1}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}=\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{n_2}{n_1}=\frac{p_2}{p_1}
$$
where the relationships among wave vector $\vec{k}$, wavelength $\lambda$, velocity $\vec{v}$, refractive index n and momentum $\vec{p}$  are shown, we arrive at the Snell's law $n_1sin\theta_1 = n_2sin\theta_2$. The perpendicular $k\perp$ component in medium 2 can be expressed in terms of medium 1's as:
$$
{k_{2y}}=\frac{n_2}{n_1}\frac{cos\theta_2}{cos\theta_1}{k_{1y}}=\sqrt{k_{1y}^2+((\frac{n_2}{n_1})^2-1){k_1}^2}
$$
and ${k_{2y}} > {k_{1y}}$ for ${n_2}>{n_1}$ as expected.

Since $\vec{p}=(h/2\pi)\vec{k}$, there is a momentum gain of from $p_1$ to $p_2$ across the boundary and it has been discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272904/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44509/). Since $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are constant speeds, there must be an impulsive photon force that is normal to the interface surface of the discontinuity. What is that normal force that pushes the photon across from 1 to 2 and why does the photon speed in medium 2 become slower? How about the law of conservation of momentum?

Comment: The concepts of energy and momentum transfer are well defined for photons. The concept of force isn't. The classical electromagnetic waves that propagate in vacuum and the medium can exert a net force at the boundary, which is used in "optical tweezer". The problem with the "photon picture" inside of optical media is that we are actually looking at an excitation of all the constituents of the matter in the medium and not just the electromagnetic field. Now electrons and the nuclei of the crystal lattice are involved. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745676.

Comment: @FlatterMann I can understand that there are interactions between photon's electric field and dielectric atoms in medium 2 like dipole moments, polarization, oscillations, etc. which give rise to dielectric constant. If momentum transfer is well defined, where does this increase of photon momentum from medium 1 to medium 2 in perpendicular direction come from?

Comment: The momentum change is transferred to the lattice. Where does the momentum come from when a ball bounces off a wall and reverses direction? It comes from the wall.