# Derivation of Fermat's Principle from the Least Action Principle

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, lagrangian-formalism, geometric-optics, variational-principle

Can I prove that Fermat's Principle (i.e. that light beam travels between two points in the path that require minimum time) using the Least Action Principle for electromagnetic wave? (from analytical mechanics).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/2451 and links therein.