# Ohmic spectral density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrical-resistance, open-quantum-systems

I am witting a paper about the non-Markovian effects of open quantum systems (a qubit interacting with a bosonic environment). I am using a spectral density of the form below:

$$
J(\omega) = \frac{\omega^S}{\omega_C^{S-1}}e^{-\omega/\omega_C}
$$

I want to know what is the physical interpretation of the $S$ quantity? I just know that $S=1$ means ohmic environment, $S>1$ super ohmic and $S<1$ subohmic, but I would like more interpretation.

and also what is the best amount for this quantity?
for example in my work, I reached $S=20$? is this a logical result?

I would really appreciate if you could help me with your answer or send me useful links.

Answer (score 14):

I like to think of the spectral density as a filter for the bosonic field frequencies, it tells you "how much" of each frequency there is. In this case, if $S=1$ you have a linear increase for low frequencies ($\omega<\omega_C$) and an exponential decay for $\omega>\omega_C$. If you put $S=2$ the increase for low $\omega$ is parabolic instead of linear. As you can see in the plot ($\omega_C=1$), subohmic spectral densities (blueish) are kind of "low-pass" filters, meaning high frequencies are heavily damped. Superohmic are more like "band-pass" filters: they damp low and high frequencies but let through those in between. Both peak at $\omega=\omega_C S$.

[image]

There is no "best amount" it depends on the envirorment you are modelling, maybe there is an envirorment which is well modelled for $S=20$, it would be one which damps heavily all frequencies below $\omega_C$ whith a sharp high-pass cut-off at $\omega=\omega_C$ then peaking at $\omega=20\omega_C$ and finally decaying exponentialy (in the plot you cant see it because its off-range). I don't know if there are envirorments whith this kind of behaviour.

I think the main reference here is the book *Quantum dissipative systems* by Ulrich Weiss, it covers spectral densities extensively.

Related:

- https://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Chapter_4.pdf (Chapter 4.2.3)
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225726556_Quantum_dissipative_systems (equation (147))
- [http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~diosi/tutorial/ohmmarkovtutor.pdf](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/%7Ediosi/tutorial/ohmmarkovtutor.pdf)
- [spectral functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56073/spectral-functions)
- [What information is contained in the quantum spectral density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155360/what-information-is-contained-in-the-quantum-spectral-density)
- [What is the relationship between the Drude form and the exponential form of Ohmic spectral density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/198267/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-drude-form-and-the-exponential-form-of-ohmi#200277)
- [Pure dephasing $\gamma_\phi$ in a master equation and noise power spectral densities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/pure-dephasing-gamma-phi-in-a-master-equation-and-noise-power-spectral-densi)
- http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Caldeira-Leggett_model

Comment: The second link (https://www.icmm.csic.es/mjcalderon/dissipativeQS.pdf) is broken. The correct link is- https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.56342. details- Quantum Dissipative Systems (F. Guinea, E. Bascones, M.J. Calderon).

Comment: Thank you! Here is an open version. I've edited the answer accordingly. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225726556_Quantum_dissipative_systems