# How is Green function in many-body theory introduced?

Tags: mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, many-body, greens-functions

Normally, for a (linear) operator $L$ and a DE

$$ Lu(x) = f(x) $$

the Green function is defined as

$$ LG(x,s) = \delta(x-s) $$

and it is found that

$$ u(x) = \int G(x,s) f(s) ds $$

is the general solution of the DE.

Now, I've read some texts about Green functions in many-body theory ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function_(many-body_theory))), but the form is unfamiliar to me.

Can you explain how those Green functions are introduced? I.e., why are objects of the form $\frac{1}{E - H_0 \pm i\eta}$ called Green functions (examples [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/the-spectral-function-in-many-body-physics-and-its-relation-to-quasiparticles) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation))?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because these are actually **Fourier transform** of the usual Green functions.
Consider the Schrödinger equation :
$$
\hat{\mathcal{H}}|\Psi(t)\rangle=\mathrm{i}\partial_t|\Psi(t)\rangle
$$
The general solution $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ of such equation for a time-independant hamiltonian $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ can be expressed in terms of Green function $G(x',x,t)$ :
$$
\Psi(x,t)=\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle=\langle x|e^{-\mathrm{i}t\hat{\mathcal{H}}}|\Psi(t=0)\rangle=\int\mathrm{d}x'\,G(x',x,t)\,\Psi(x',t=0)
$$
where $G(x',x,t)=\langle x'|e^{-\mathrm{i}t\hat{\mathcal{H}}}|x\rangle$. The last equality is obtained by introducing the closure identity :
$$
\int\mathrm{d}x'\,|x'\rangle\langle x'|=\hat{1}
$$

One can then define a *Green operator* :
$$
\hat{G}(t)=-\mathrm{i}\,\Theta(t)\,e^{-\mathrm{i}t\hat{\mathcal{H}}}
$$
where $\Theta$ stands for the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) which is here to ensure the *causality* of the solution $\Psi(x,t)$.

Then, one can compute the Fourier transform of such operator, which sometimes is called *resolvent operator* :
$$
\hat{G}(\epsilon)=\int\mathrm{d}t\,\hat{G}(t)\,e^{\mathrm{i}\epsilon t}=-\mathrm{i}\int\mathrm{d}t\,\Theta(t)\,e^{\mathrm{i}t(\epsilon-\hat{\mathcal{H}})}
$$

Then one can express the $\Theta$ function in terms of its Fourier transform :
$$
\Theta(t)=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\omega-\mathrm{i}\eta}
$$
where $\eta$ is a positive infinitesimal parameter.

Taking all of this together, you will find that :
$$
\hat{G}(\epsilon)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{\omega-\mathrm{i}\eta}\int\mathrm{d}t\,e^{\mathrm{i}t(\epsilon-\omega-\hat{\mathcal{H}})}
$$
It is possible to recognize with the Fourier transform of the Dirac distribution :
$$
\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\mathrm{d}t\,e^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}
$$
that :
$$
\hat{G}(\epsilon)=-\int\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{\omega-\mathrm{i}\eta}\;\delta(\omega+\epsilon-\hat{\mathcal{H}})=\frac{1}{\epsilon+\mathrm{i}\eta-\hat{\mathcal{H}}}
$$
which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I understood everything except the second formula. Can you explain why this $\Psi$ is truly a solution of the Schrödinger equation?

Comment: See edit $\uparrow$ for more precision.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a minus sign mistake, as you have $it(\epsilon - \omega -H)$ in the exponential, and then this becomes $\omega + \epsilon - H$ in the delta function.