# What is a quasi-photon (⁠•⁠ ⁠▽⁠ ⁠•⁠;⁠)?

Tags: photons, identical-particles, quasiparticles

Regarding the question-

[Do quasiphotons have mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/751290/do-quasiphotons-have-mass)

Could someone explain to me what a quasi-photon is in layman's terms?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _quasiphoton_. The quasiparticle produced by the interaction of light with a medium is called _polariton_ and [you can read about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton).

Comment: @John Rennie- Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Please don’t put text art in titles, or elsewhere.